# Sequences ${a_k}$ and ${c_k}$ such that $a_k$, $c_k \rightarrow 0$, $\sum_k a_k = \infty$, and $\sum_k\left(\frac{a_k}{c_k}\right )^{2} < \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

Is there an example of two sequences for which the following conditions hold?

Sequences ${a_k}$ and ${c_k}$ such that $a_k$, $c_k \rightarrow 0$, $\sum_k a_k = \infty$, and $\sum_k\left(\frac{a_k}{c_k}\right )^{2} < \infty $

Comment: $a_k = 1/k$, $c_k = 1/k^{1/4}$.

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: Indeed, for *any* sequence $\{a_k\}$ such that $\sum a_k^2 < \infty$ (including those for which $\sum a_k = \infty$), there exists a sequence $\{c_k\}$ with $c_k\to0$ such that $\sum (a_k/c_k)^2 < \infty$.